# Import Contents from multiple CSV files and Add column for CSV Filename

Tags: sql-server

Here’s the problem:

I need to capture a portion of a file name and load it in to a table along with the contents of that file which is a CSV file. The files will be stored in to a folder and will consists of multiple files. I will not know what the file names are. All files will be named using the same format.

So, here is a breakdown of how it will look.

RDBMS: SQL Server 2008 R2
Filename format: xx_xxxx_SERVERNAME1_date.csv
File Content: Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4 (delimiter used – comma)

I need to capture only the SERVERNAME portion of the file name as well as all the content within that file.

So, the table will/should look like this:
Server_Name         Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4
SERVERNAME1         XXX         XXX         XXX         XXX
SERVERNAME1         XXX         XXX         XXX         XXX
SERVERNAME1         XXX         XXX         XXX         XXX
SERVERNAME2         XXX         XXX         XXX         XXX
SERVERNAME2         XXX         XXX         XXX         XXX
SERVERNAME2         XXX         XXX         XXX         XXX
SERVERNAME3         XXX         XXX         XXX         XXX

Each server name in the first column is derived from the SERVERNAME portion of the file name and Columns 1 – 4 is derived from the content within the file. It should loop through the folder and repeat until all filenames and content have been inserted into the table.

I’m not sure what the best solution is to achieve this. I have a C# program that I found that works great if it was just a matter of capturing the content and loading into a table. I can also use SSIS to read the content.

My problem is capturing the filename data and then associating it with that content from that file.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this using SSIS and a Foreach Loop Container and specifying the file name as a variable.  Within the Foreach Loop Container you would have a data flow task that imports the file and within the data flow task you would include a derived column transformation.  In the derived column transformation you can create a new column and pass in the variable for the file name as the expression.  You can then use this new column as source and import both the file contents and the file name into the table.